# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered in the local machine.'

Tags: asp.net, database, oledb, oledbconnection

I have installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 on the Windows 2008 server. However, when I ran my web application to import a spreadsheet table to the database. It complains with the error message - **"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered in the local machine."**

I have tested my code and works in my Windows 7 local machine. Any idea?

Comment: Is the OS x64? Are you targeting x86 on an x64 machine?

Comment: Yes, it is a x64 machine. Yes, I am targeting x86 on x64.

Comment: So did you install the x86 version of the redist or x64? I hope you installed x86. If you want try installing both versions and see it helps. Also SP1 for both x86 and x64 versions are avaiable: (x86) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26607 (x64) : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26605

Comment: Thanks @GaneshR. I tried both version but they did not work either.

Comment: Do you need to set up a Data Source in the control panel data sources?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/43d6b544-7172-4fe7-babf-a541e5f6a1c9

Comment: Check this out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64 Also it seems Office is required on the machine. Is that true?

Answer (score 7):

There is a **problem** with **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12** when **AccessDatabaseEngine** x86 or x64 ***2010*** is installed.

I have long attempted to use the SSMS (2005-2008-2008R2-2012) Export Wizards to export large tables onto Excel and I needed the AccessDatabaseEngine installed to be able to do that.

However, regardless of the MS Office version (2010, x86 or x64, or whatever it is), the 2010 version of AccessDatabaseEngine will not work towards registering the provider.

The solution is to download and install the previous one which is none other than the **2007 x86** one.
This one will work even if Office or SQL Server or VS are x64.

Download it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Now, any other propagated issues revolving around the notorious failure to register "the provider" on the local machine for the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12 should be resolved by the above.

Feel free to paste me your experiences on this matter.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a million.