# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Is not registered, unable to fix after Access Database Engine 2010 download

Tags: c#, ms-access, installation, oledb

This error drives me crazy. I have added an access DB to my project as a data source (to bind it with components in my form) and because of this not only that I am unable to connect to the database, but I am also unable to run the whole project!

the full error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered in the local machin.
  Source=System.Data
```

I have tried to download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 (as ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered in the local machine.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042855/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine) said) and was not helpful. unable to find 2007 version. and tried to run on x86 and still same error. why is this not working? what I should do?

[Here is the error when trying to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8EKI.png)

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638851/3110834

Comment: Are you sure you are downloading the right version.  What is your operating system ? For windows10 you need Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016

Comment: @sk2185 do you believe that the problem is in the conn string?

Comment: yes might be the cause.

Comment: @ywwy I have tried to download 2019 version 64 and it says that I need to delete the 32 version office before I do that. what he wants me to delete and how I delete it?

Comment: @Aviv Vetaro What is your operating system ? And  Is it 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: @sk2185 I got my conn string from VS itself... So I doubt he is wrong. and I think that the error generates from the binding of the object to the DB and for that binding, it uses auto-generated config conn string. maybe I didn't set it right?

Comment: @ywwy Win10 and I believe that 64 bit, But I'm not sure

Comment: you can use it. but some change based on access version will do.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Is this what I should do? I have tried that and it's not working

Comment: @Aviv Vetaro in Explorer goto my computer, right click properties and find system type.  Then install the right version from here [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all)

Comment: @ywwy checked and its x64 indeed. And when I try to download the x64 version I get the above error > delete the 32 version office before I do that

Comment: @Aviv Vetaro  In the additional information of the installation details : "If Office 365 is already installed, side by side detection will prevent the installation from proceeding.    Open an administrative command prompt, and provide the installation path and switch Ex: C:\Files\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet"   Maybe you have Office 365 (it is mostly 32 bit).

Comment: @ywwy yes I have. so should I open ```cmd``` and type ```C:\Files\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet``` I have tried that and it says it can't find the path.

Comment: @Aviv Vetaro open cmd prompt as admin (right click "run as administrator").   I suppose the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe file wil be in your downloads folder.   change the path to that folder.

Comment: AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe

Comment: did it solve your problem ?

Comment: @ywwy spent 4 hours deleting all the ```ACEOLEDB.DLL``` files still same error. what have I done wrong

Comment: I've tried to fix this a couple times and it's a true PITA. I just created the db as an Access 2003 db, problem solved.